# Locked SSD: Am I out of luck?

Tags: ssd, sata

I've managed to get myself into a bind. I have a OCZ Vertex 2 SSD that has a low level lock turned on (seems to be from a failed secure erase with parted magic, though not sure).

I'm hammering at this drive with MHDD, trying to do an UNLOCK followed by DISPWD so that I could get on with my life, but it is rejecting all attempts at password entry for me. I've never set up a password on the drive, so I assume the password is default. I've tried:

- null
- NULL
- ""

And also tried just hitting ENTER at the password prompt, but no go. Is there any other default password that I can try here? Or maybe there are some games I can play with powering on the drive post-boot?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed my issue by using the OCZ supplied bootable ISO to instead secure erase the drive again.

http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?105168-NEW!!-PC-Bootable-Toolbox

Be aware that for some reason, booting up to the OCZ ISO took *forever*, during what was supposed to be a 15 second count down, each second instead took 20 minutes. It eventually finished booting though.

I also made sure to do a proper system shutdown after doing the secure erase, to try and make sure that security mode for the drive was disabled.